# Create a table row in between 2 rows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I create a table row in between 2  ?
I am using the code below to create a row.

```
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
         tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY").item(0);

         row=document.createElement("TR");

         cell1 = document.createElement("TD");

         textnode1=document.createTextNode('');

         cell1.appendChild(textnode1);


         row.appendChild(cell1);

         tabBody.appendChild(row);


}
```

Actually I want to create it as a middle row. Currently my table has 2 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table exposes its own methods that can be used to modify it:

```
- insertRow 
- deleteRow
```

A table row exposes a method that can be used to insert a new cell:
`insertCell`.
[Here](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tablebasics1.html) are some basic examples.

Answer (score 1):

Table elements have [their own methods for manipulating them](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-64060425), so you can use the [`.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow) method and the [`.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/tableRow.insertCell)

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var middleRow = table.insertRow( Math.floor( table.rows.length / 2 ) );
var cell1 = middleRow.insertCell(0);
var textnode1=document.createTextNode('');
cell1.appendChild( textnode1 );
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yA7Rg/

Answer (score 0):

try using insertBefore; begin by calculating the index of middle row then insertBefore the nextSibling to get the row to the right index

```
tabBody.insertBefore(row, tabBody.childNodes[0].nextSibling);
```